# How to use binding data in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a series of buttons to increase, display, and decrease the *int* month.

```
<Button Content="+" Name="btnAddMonth"/>
<Button Content="{Binding Path=month}" Name="btnMonth"/>
<Button Content="-" Name="btnMinusMonth"/>
```

I have a button to save such data.

```
<Button Content="Save Changes" Name="btnSaveChanges" Click="btnSaveChanges_Click"/></Button>
```

**How would I implement such that I can use a value (most notably, the *int* value of `Content={Binding Path=month}` for `btnMonth`) in the code behind?** I have found that using the name of the button isn't the way to go. I believe I have to use a `Converter` in this case, but am unsure on how to approach implementing it.

```
public void btnSaveChanges_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //use *int* value of month here
    //eg - updateMonth(/* value of {Binding Path=month} */);      
}
```

**EDIT**: A more complete example

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ABC.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ConvertMonth x:Key="ConvertMonth"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="+" Name="btnAddMonth" Click="btnAddMonth_Click"/>
        <Button Content="{Binding ElementName=Month, Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource ConvertMonth}}"/>
        <Button Content="-" Name="btnMinusMonth" Click="btnMinusMonth_Click"/>

        <Button Content="Save Changes" Name=btnSaveChanges Click="btnSaveChanges_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace ABC
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSaveChanges_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var mm = ConvertMonth.GetMonth();
            DateTime date = new DateTime(mm);
        }

        public void btnAddMonth_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int h = Convert.ToInt16(btnMonth.Content.ToString());

            if (h < 12)
            {
                int x = h + 1;

                if (h < 9)
                {
                    btnMonth.Content = x.ToString();
                }

                else
                {
                    btnMonth.Content = x.ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnMinusMonth_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int h = Convert.ToInt16(btnMonth.Content.ToString());

            if (h > 1)
            {
                int x = h - 1;
                if (h < 11)
                {
                    btnMonth.Content = x.ToString();
                }

                else
                {
                    btnMonth.Content = x.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class ConvertMonth : IValueConverter
    {
        private static int _month;

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            object result = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

            if (value is double)
                result = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(System.Convert.ToInt32(value));

            DateTime d = System.Convert.ToDateTime(result);
            _month = d.Month;

            return result;
        }

        public static int GetMonth()
        {
            return _month;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to tell us where and how 'month' is declared.  On whose path does 'month' reside?

Comment: 'Month' is a local declaration of type `int`...will edit to display more detail.

Comment: Fair enough, then what does the + button do?  How does it increment the Month?

Comment: I have an update function to call in the code behind in which I need to get the int value.

Comment: Your original question excluded the click events on the buttons and code-behind handlers.  Your edit provided an entirely different problem space.

Comment: I wasn't necessarily interested in including the click events because they work...I was more interested in getting the content of `btnMonth` and use its integer value to pass through an update function to do some back-end interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon what you have provided, you can change this...

```
public void btnSaveChanges_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //use *int* value of month here
    //eg - updateMonth(/* value of {Binding Path=month} */);      
}
```

to...

```
public void btnSaveChanges_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int numberOfMonths = Convert.ToInt32(btnMonth.Content);   
}
```

That answers your question.  Per commentary, it appears that the + and - buttons do not interact with the content of the button that should contain the integer.

Comment: And then put the `numberOfMonths` in the update function...but `btnMonth.Content` is really what I'm looking for.